# What was the first work involving Nazis and occult magic?

Tags: magic, history-of, nazis

There is a pretty common theme in pulp period stories involving Nazis of the Nazis being involved with searching for or wielding evil magic.  To me, this is most associated with the Indiana Jones movies.  In *Raiders of the Lost Ark*, one of the government men who hires Jones says that Hilter is "obsessed with the occult."  In fact, Hitler was not, but Himmler, the head of the SS, was fascinated by the occult.

I'm curious where this originated, since I suspect that it must have been around before Indiana Jones.  Of course, there are two slightly different version of this motif; there is a more realistic version and a fantasy version in which the magic is real.  I am primarily interested in the fantasy version, but I wouldn't mind hearing about how the more realistic version influenced development of the occult Nazis theme.

Comment: Well, my **favorite** was [Wolfenstein 3D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfenstein_3D); everything from Undead minions and Zombies to the Spear of Destiny :)

Comment: It might interest you to know that the Nazis *genuinely* incorporated elements of the occult into their inner-circle practices, hence the trope.

Comment: I think what you mean is - *what was the first such work in which Nazis were bad guys* :)  Otherwise you may want to look at actual Nazi theosophy and parts of Mein Kampf.

Comment: If you are looking for the first external (non-party) work that addresses it, I think my answer below has it.. But if you are looking for internal (nazi-party) info, that's an entirely different question.. as Valorum points out, they DID incorporate quite a but of occult into their practices, at least at certain levels.

Comment: [Does voodoo count?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_of_the_Zombies)

Comment: Researching this mad me find out how many people are serious about magic explanation of nazis

Comment: @MishaRosnach Well, *Mein Kampf* and actual Nazi theosophy don't count as SFF.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My bet on the first fiction association beween nazis and occult magic is Strange Conflict by [Dennis Wheatley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennis_Wheatley) published in 1941.

> When the bombs fall on London the elderly Duke de Richleau considers a problem of the utmost urgency. What methods are the Germans using to discover – with sinister effect – the secret routes of the Atlantic convoys? His answer is bizarre and fantastic. The enemy are in touch with supernatural powers which can be overcome only by those who have the knowledge and courage to join battle with them on the Astral Plane. The Duke and his supporters face the terrifying challenge from the Powers of Darkness
>
> *Summary from [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3008660-strange-conflict-duke-de-richleau-9)*

Answer (score 6):

Since you don't specify what media you are looking for, I'm going to go with the earliest I'm aware of, [*The Morning of the Magicians*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Morning_of_the_Magicians), a 1960 non-fiction book by Louis Pauwels and Jacques Bergier.  It speculates on the origins of Nazism being successors to the [Vril](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vril#Vril_Society) and [Thule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thule_Society) Societies.

[**Note**: This is the first "Real-world" analysis (taken with a grain of salt; it's questionable how legitimate it is) I could find indicating the link between Nazism and the Occult; if you are looking for the first fantasy portrayal of it, that's a different story.]

You may also find this article on [Occultism in Nazism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occultism_in_Nazism) (from Wikipedia) to be of interest.

Comment: Note that (unless I've misinterpreted the Wikipedia article?) this book is non-fiction, which might not be quite what the OP is looking for.

Comment: It's a good question; it's written as if it was fact, but the authors don't actually say it is...  From the Occultism article "*One could also ask whether The Morning of the Magicians should not be considered as fiction, since the authors fail to clearly state that it was supposed to be fact.*"